# Extract JSON Data with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Suppose below is my JSON data

```
{"pricing": {
     "com": {
         "addons": {
                "dns": true,
                "email": true,
                "idprotect": true
       },
     "org": {
         "addons": {
                "dns": true,
                "email": true,
                "idprotect": true
       },
     "net": {
         "addons": {
                "dns": true,
                "email": true,
                "idprotect": true
       }
}}
```

I want to display only (com, org, net) from above JSON. How can we do that?

Comment: You only want to display the keys `com` etc?

Comment: yes @Thefourthbird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option to do this is to use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and pass `true` for the second parameter to convert the returned objects into associative arrays.

To display only the keys you could loop `$output["pricing"]` using a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and display the keys:

```
$json = '{"pricing": {"com": {"addons": {"dns": true,"email": true,"idprotect": true}},"org": {"addons": {"dns": true,"email": true,"idprotect": true}},"net": {"addons": {"dns": true,"email": true,"idprotect": true}}}}';
$output = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($output["pricing"] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . "<br>";
}
```

Another way could be to get the [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and loop them:

```
foreach (array_keys($output["pricing"]) as $key) {
    echo $key . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Also, what can we do to make it a PHP array?

Comment: It returns as 'Array ( [0] => com [1] => org [2] => net' what if we want to return as array('com', 'org', 'net') ?

Comment: That [is the same](https://3v4l.org/baN9G) only without numerical keys. Check out [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

First u had a incorrect JSON format check it out. I think this solution might help you!!

```
$json = '{"pricing": {"com": {"addons": {"dns": true,"email": true,"idprotect": true}},"org": {"addons": {"dns": true,"email": true,"idprotect": true}},"net": {"addons": {"dns": true,"email": true,"idprotect": true}}}}';
$output = json_decode($json);

print_r($output->pricing->com->addons);
print_r($output->pricing->org->addons);
print_r($output->pricing->net->addons);
```

You will get something like this !!

```
stdClass Object ( [dns] => 1 [email] => 1 [idprotect] => 1 ) 
stdClass Object ( [dns] => 1 [email] => 1 [idprotect] => 1 ) 
stdClass Object ( [dns] => 1 [email] => 1 [idprotect] => 1 )
```

Comment: I only want to echo - com,org,net

Comment: `foreach($output->pricing as $key=>$value)
{
 echo $key;
}
` Will it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ??

```
 $json = '{"pricing": {"com": {"addons": {"dns": true,"email": true,"idprotect": true}},"org": {"addons": {"dns": true,"email": true,"idprotect": true}},"net": {"addons": {"dns": true,"email": true,"idprotect": true}}}}';
$output = json_decode($json,true);

echo implode(",",array_keys($output["pricing"]));
```

com,org,net